# eclipse plugin modifying launch configuration files

Tags: eclipse, plugins, configuration, classpath, launch

I have a problem. I moved from Eclipse Helios to Eclipse Indigo and there is one problem. The old launch configurations doesnt works, because in Indigo is a different maven plugin. so when i run a program i get an following Error message:

Referenced classpath provider does not exist: org.maven.ide.eclipse.launchconfig.classpathProvider

I know, how to fix it but I need write a plugin which can do it for me without changing the launch configuration. So probably need to add to an new eclipse classpath which can point to new version of maven. something like:

when configuration containts "org.maven.ide.eclipse.launchconfig.classpathProvider" use "org.eclipse.m2e.launchconfig.classpathProvider".

Is anyone know ho to expand launchconfiguration classpaths ?

Answer (score 3):

Below in the launch file works for me

```
<stringAttribute
    key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_PROVIDER"
    value="org.eclipse.m2e.launchconfig.classpathProvider"/>
```

earlier it was this:

```
<stringAttribute
    key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_PROVIDER"
    value="org.maven.ide.eclipse.launchconfig.classpathProvider"/>
```

Comment: This solution works only when you are trying to use eclipse launch created for Eclipse Maven Plugin when M2Eclipse plugin is currently in use.